# Arrow lines crooked when using xymatrix frame around group of entries

Tags: tikz-arrows, xy-pic

The following does not yield squared arrow lines.  The lines connecting the two lower blocks are crooked. Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Thanks,
Dave

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\xymatrix {
        {\scriptsize\begin{array}{ll}z\\~\\~\end{array}}
    &
    &   *+++++[F]{G}    \ar@<-9pt>[ll]
                        \ar@{->}`l/0pt[ld]`[d]_{y}[d]
                        \ar@{<-}`r/0pt[rd]`[d]^{v}[d]
    &
    &   {\scriptsize\begin{array}{ll}w\\~\\~\end{array}}            
                        \ar@<-9pt>[ll]
\\
    &
    &   *+++++[F]{K}    \ar@<+9pt>@{->}`l/0pt[ld]`[d]_{x}[d]
                        \ar@<-9pt>@{<-}`r/0pt[rd]`[d]^{u}[d]
    &
\\
    &
    &   *++[F]{Q}
    &
}
```

Comment: `xy` is really not the tool for such diagrams. Take a look on TikZ or pstricks. Maybe something from here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/ or have a look in the pgf manual.

Answer (score 1):

Text aligned in matrix kind of fashion that are connected with lines?
[TikZ-CD](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) seems convenient enough for this.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}% https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext
\tikzset{
  r-lr/.style={to path={r-lr(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  r-rl/.style={to path={r-rl(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}}
\tikzcdset{
  % shift left/right won't work with the r-lr/r-rl paths
  @squeeze/.style 2 args={
    start anchor={[#1shift=(#2)*(
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/shift left/.@def})]},
    end anchor={[#1shift=-(#2)*(
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/shift left/.@def})]}},
  squeeze up/.style={@squeeze={y}{#1}},   squeeze up/.default=1,
  squeeze down/.style={@squeeze={y}{-(#1)}}, squeeze down/.default=1,
  /tikz/tiny nodes/.style={nodes={
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, minimum size=+0pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  /tikz/column 2/.append style={minimum size=1cm, nodes=draw},
  % we could do these arrows without node in column 1 and 3
  % but this gives us a convenient target
  % (coordinates don't work nicely with shift left/right
  /tikz/column 1/.append style=tiny nodes,
  /tikz/column 3/.append style=tiny nodes,
  swap % all the labels are on the wrong side
]
  {}
& G  \arrow[l,     "z" {at end, left}, shift right=2]
     \arrow[r, <-, "w" {at end, right}, shift left=2]
     \arrow[d, r-lr, "y", squeeze down]
& {}
\\
& K \arrow[d, r-lr, "y", squeeze down]
    \arrow[u, r-rl, "v", squeeze up]
\\
& Q \arrow[u, r-rl, "u", squeeze up]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]